# What are the official requirements to host ASP.NET MVC 5 on a server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hosting, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to find out what my company will need on our servers to utilise MVC5 but I'm seeing a lot of contradictory or out of date information and I can't find any official data. Some say Windows Server 2008 with IIS7 and .NET 4.5, other Windows Server 2012 with IIS8, and there is also mention of it possibly running on IIS6.

So which server OS, version of IIS, .NET framework, and any other libraries are required to host MVC5? If there are different levels of hosting that would also be helpful to know. Please don't suggest third party hosting companies.

Answer (score -2):

To install MVC 5 you should have installed ASP.NET 4.5.

Comment: Do you have a source for this opinion? It's almost certainly right but I really need to know the *official* requirements

Comment: Also your answer doesn't mention which OS or IIS version is required